# How to commit inline edits to database

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I am building a website in Flask. I made a form that takes input and also renders records from the database. I need help processing any changes made to the records it retrieves from the database. For example, If a user inputs 1pm for monday and 2pm for sunday. The form will process the input and display it. But if I want to change 1pm to 3pm, I cannot. It lets me do inline edits but does not commit the changes to the database.
The following files are as follow:

schedule.html:

```
                 {% for r in result %}
                  <div class="form-inline">

                    <form class="form-schedule" method="post" action="/schedule/update">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" id="inputMonday" name="monday" class="form-control" value="{{ r.monday }}" required autofocus>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" id="inputSunday" name="sunday" class="form-control" value="{{ r.sunday }}" required autofocus>
                      </div>
                      {% endfor %}
                      </br>
                      <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" type="submit">Save</button>
                    </form>
```

views.py:

```
@home.route('/schedule')
@login_required
def schedule():
    """
    Render the schedule template on the /schedule route
    """
    result = Schedule.query.filter_by(persons_id = current_user.id)

    return render_template('home/schedule.html', title="Schedule", result=result)

@home.route('/schedule/update', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
@login_required
def schedule_update():
    """
    Process the schedule then render schedule route
    """
    monday = request.form['monday']
    sunday = request.form['sunday']
    persons_id = 1
    employees_id = 1

    days = Schedule(monday=monday, sunday=sunday, persons_id=persons_id, employees_id=employees_id)
    db.session.add(days)
    db.session.commit()
    return redirect(url_for('home.schedule'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are not reading the schedule from the database before saving it.  Use the query.get method to read it from the database.  Add an id to your form as follows:

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{r.id}}">
```

Then in the `schedule_update` method read the id from the POST data.

```
schedule_id = request.form['id']
# read existing schedule from the database
days = Schedule.query.get(int(schedule_id))

if not days:
    abort(404)

days.monday = monday
days.sunday = sunday
days.persons_id = 1
days.employees_ie = 1

db.session.add(days)
db.session.commit()
return redirect(url_for('home.schedule'))
```

Comment: It works. I can changed one row in the schedule table! I'm gonna add some code to generate more rows and adjust to work for them. But thank you so much. You gave me a great reply at a time when I was about to lose faith in StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

What you're currently doing is creating a new object and saving it to the database. What you need to do is to retrieve the object to be edited from the database and and then apply edits to that object.

`day = db.session.query(Schedule).filter_by(id=id).first()`

This should query the database and get you the object. And then apply edits on this and finally commit it to the database.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Your solution works too. But now I'm having trouble getting it to work with multiple rows. Whenever a change is made to row 1 it also changes row 2. I don't want it to do that. I want the data in each row to change independently based on whatever input changes the user made. I don't know the proper search terms to google for this type of problem. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by “whenever a change is made to row 1, it also changes row 2?” Please provide more info along with some specific use case as an example

Comment: Ok, so here is how my template looks for schedule.html: (https://imagebin.ca/v/3cXBfCXVk7UQ). First of all, the number of employees showing up in the schedule is duplicated for some reason. But anyways, whenever I make a change to the first row it would also change the second row. I want the changes to be made independently.

Comment: Show me your models.

Comment: It's not needed anymore. I decided to go a different route. Thanks for the help though.